# The ajax call not showing the upload image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am uploading a file and when I hit upload I want to display an image till the time ajax call doesn't send a response.

Here is my code-:

```
    $(function() {
    $('#upload-file-btn').click(function(e) {
        if ($('#uploading').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
            $('#uploading').css('visibility','visible');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        var form_data = new FormData($('#upload-file')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/uploadCSV',
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {

                if (data.errorMsg){
                    alert(data.errorMsg);
                    if ($('#uploading').css('visibility') == 'visible') {
                       $('#uploading').css('visibility','hidden');
                    }
                    return;
                }
                if ($('#uploading').css('visibility') == 'visible') {
                    $('#uploading').css('visibility','hidden');
                }
                $("#add-new").remove();
                $(".panel-close").remove();

                var formLists = data.formList;
                populateFormDict = data.populateFormDict;
                console.log(formLists);
                console.log(populateFormDict);

                for (var i in formLists) {
                    var context = "#offer-panel-"+(parseInt(i)+1);
                    var inputContext = "input#panel-"+(parseInt(i)+1);
                    $(context).show();
                    $(inputContext).val('on');
                    $("#formatLevel", context).html(formLists[i].format_level);
                    $("#bu", context).empty();
                    $('#bu', context).html(formLists[i].bu);
                    $('#bu option', context).prop('selected', true);
                    $("#bu option:selected", context).attr('disabled',true)
                    $("#bu", context).multiselect({
                        noneSelectedText: 'Select Options',
                        selectedList: 1,
                        create: function(event, ui) {
                            created_2 = event.timeStamp;
                        },
                        beforeopen: function(event, ui) {},
                        open: function(event, ui) {},
                        close: function(event, ui) {
                            categories = $("#bu", context).val();
                            console.log(categories);
                        },
                        checkall: function(event, ui) {
                            checkall_2 = event.timeStamp - created_2;
                            console.info("time :" + checkall_2);
                        }
                    }).multiselectfilter().multiselect("enable");
                    $("#bu", context).multiselect("refresh");
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

The html for this is-:

```
<img src="../static/img/uploading.jpg" id="uploading" style="display:none; margin: 0; padding:0; top:0; left:0; width: 100%;
height: 100%; background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5); width: 100px; position:fixed; " />
```

When I hit the upload button then the image doesn't show up. The form for uploading a file is-:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-file">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input type="file" name="offersFile" class="form-control col-md-4" id="fileInput" >
        </div>
        <button id="upload-file-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

I am unable to understand where is the error.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing the visibility and the display properties, they are not the same. Try this:

```
if (!$('#uploading').is(':visible')) {
  $('#uploading').show(); // or fadeIn/slideDown to animate the display of the image
}
```

Comment: @user7519395 if you remove the `if` condition it works? The image is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Why use css property when you can use jquery's `show()` function.

```
  $('#uploading').show();
```

eg:

```
if ($('#uploading').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
    $('#uploading').show();
}
```

best way

```
if (! $('#uploading').is(":visible")){
   $('#uploading').show();
}

and

if ($('#uploading').is(":visible")){
   $('#uploading').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`visibility` and `display` are 2 different CSS properties:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

> The visibility CSS property can show or hide an element without
>   affecting the layout of a document (i.e., space is created for
>   elements regardless of whether they are visible or not). The property
>   can also hide rows or columns in a .

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

> The display CSS property specifies the type of rendering box used for
>   an element. In HTML, default display property values are taken from
>   behaviors described in the HTML specifications or from the
>   browser/user default stylesheet. The default value in XML is inline,
>   including SVG elements.
>        In addition to the many different display box types, the value none lets you turn off the display of an element; when you use none,
>   all descendant elements also have their display turned off. The
>   document is rendered as though the element doesn't exist in the
>   document tree.

In your html code you are setting the display Property

```
<img src="../static/img/uploading.jpg" id="uploading" style="display:none; margin: 0; padding:0; top:0; left:0; width: 100%;
height: 100%; background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5); width: 100px; position:fixed; " />
```

While in javascript you are changing a different property:

```
 if ($('#uploading').css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
        $('#uploading').css('visibility','visible');
    }
```

and that's why the image doesn't show, so you need to use the same property on both for example change your js to be:

```
 if ($('#uploading').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('#uploading').css('display','block');
    }
```

or better use:

```
  if ($('#uploading').is(':visible')) {
        $('#uploading').show();
    }
```

or much better use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)